# NUnit failed to load, using version 3.11

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nuget, nunit, nunit-3.0

When I lower to 3.10 it works and am not sure why it's stopped for latest. Everything I try is not working.

This is what shows in the output. I tried many of the options found online, but nothing seems to be helping:

```
[13/03/2019 17:10:44 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[13/03/2019 17:10:45 Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
[13/03/2019 17:10:45 Informational] Running all tests in E:\xxx\xxx\xxx.Tests\bin\Debug\xxx.Tests.dll
[13/03/2019 17:10:45 Informational]    NUnit failed to load E:\xxx\xxx\xxx.xxx\bin\Debug\xxx.Tests.dll
[13/03/2019 17:10:45 Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution complete
[13/03/2019 17:10:45 Warning] No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=xxx.xxx.xxxTestss.xxxxnameshouldbesomething` in E:\xxx\xxx\xxx.Tests\bin\Debug\xxx.Tests.dll
[13/03/2019 17:10:45 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:01.6716706) ==========
```

I created a basic test to confirm too, here:

```
Imports NUnit.Framework
Imports Should

<TestFixture()>
Public Class UnitTest1

    <Test()> Public Sub TestMethod1()
        Dim b As Boolean = False
        b.ShouldBeFalse
    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried removing TestFixture, renaming it to TestClass (but I need to use NUnit!)

So strange... it doesn't help that I have a project in the solution that does work, and I can't find any difference.

I even tried to create a new empty project... but that doesn't even work on any version of NUnit (but I think I will raise that as a separate issue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem found, for some reason, the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework flag "Copy Local" was set to false for my project.

When i change this to true my tests are now being picked up and running : )

Version 3.10 didnt seem to need this, which is why when lowering version, it started working again.

(I didnt think having this flag set would effect running local)

Comment: I'm having a similar trouble with NUnit 3.12. Where is this flag located?

Comment: @akarnokd sorry, have only just seen this... when you click the reference in solution explorer, at the bottom in "properties", you should see this flag

Comment: This one also helped me. Thanks!

Comment: it worked for me, but I'm wondering why Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework need to be "Copy Local". How is it related to NUnit?