# Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.5 NUnit failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nunit-3.0

Neither vanila Visual studio or with resharper run tests.

All tests are discovered and appear in test explorer.

Tests **not run** in test explorer and all tests **inconclusive** in resharper.

The **output** window for **tests** shows the following:

```
NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0: Test discovery starting
NUnit failed to load mytests.dll 
NUnit Adapter 3.16.1.0: Test discovery complete
No test is available in mytests.dll Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

I have tried all solutions listed in other answers but to no avail:

- Closing and restarting the Visual Studio Solution.
- Deleting .vs folder.
- Adding NUnit3 Test adapter.
- Setting x64 bit CPU
- Converting packages.config to package references

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55237334/393672) helped me. I assume this is your case too.

Comment: Cannot tell as I unfortunately do not have access to this code base